# Laptop shuts down even though I just briefly press the power button

Tags: shutdown

My laptop is quite old so sometimes annoying errors happen here.

Normally if you briefly press the power button, a small menu with 4 options pops up. You can put suspend, restart or shut it down. Somehow my laptop wont suspend, even though I closed the lid, so I have to do it by pressing the power button.
Now recently when doing this, and whenever I have lots of tabs and documents open, my laptop would immediately shut down. This is unusual and frustrating, since I have to waste lots of time to reboot it.

Is it because the graphics card is simply worn out? Or what other explanations can you all find?

Its an EasyNote LV44HC with Ubuntu 14.04

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Does it do it even with nothing open? If it still does, then I'd say it's more of a hardware related issue rather than a problem with software.

If it does it all the time even with nothing open, it's possible that the physical hardware power button is worn out, and a slight press is getting stuck down, so the computer thinks you're still pressing it even though you're not.

I'd also try to check what setting you have in *Settings -> Power -> Suspend and Power Button.*
On 18.04, mine is set to suspend when I have the power button pressed, and it behaves just like that, but only when I hold the button down. I believe you have a hardware issue, and highly doubt a worn out graphics card would cause this issue.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not yet have enough reputation to post a comment directly to the thread and figured I'd help OP out.